# Why aren't my variables evaluated in this function?

Tags: function-construction, evaluation

Consider this code :

```
Clear[Ptest]

Ptest[1, 1] = p + Theta;

Ptest[1, 2] = 2*p + Theta;

Ptest[1, 3] = 3*p + Theta;

Ptest[1, 4] = 4*p + Theta;

Clear[test]

test[x_, p_, Theta_] = Sum[Ptest[x, k], {k, 1, 4}];

test[1, 1, 2]

(*10 p + 4 Theta*)

test[1, p, Theta]

(*10 p + 4 Theta*)
```

I don't understand why the variables p and Theta are not replaced in the before the last line ? Indeed in the very last line we see that the function has the good values.

**So : first question *why* when I give explicit numbers to p and Theta, nothing is computed ?**

And after the why it does this, how to fix it properly (without making replacement rules).

I would like to avoid replacing Ptest by its exact expression as a function of p and Theta (because in my code it would be complicated for my own purpose). Thus I would like to keep something like

```
test[x_,p_,Theta_]=Sum[Ptest[x,k],{k,1,4}]
```

without writing explicit dependance inside of the function definition (because maybe there is some "magic" function to add around to make it work).

**So second question : how to fix the code without having to write the explicit function of p and theta inside the definition of test ?**

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) to temporarily set the values for `Theta` and `p` globally:

```
Clear[Ptest]

Ptest[1, 1] = p + Theta;
Ptest[1, 2] = 2*p + Theta;
Ptest[1, 3] = 3*p + Theta;
Ptest[1, 4] = 4*p + Theta;

Clear[test]

test[x_, p2_, Theta2_] := Block[{Theta = Theta2, p = p2}, Sum[Ptest[x, k], {k, 1, 4}]];

test[1, 1, 2]
(* 18 *)

test[1, p, Theta]
(* 10 p + 4 Theta *)
```

Note that in order for it to work, you need to use [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) (`:=`) for the definition of `test`, since `Block` disappears upon evaluation. The parameters also need different names.